# Why is Python re not splitting multiple instances of punctuation?

Tags: python, split, python-re, punctuation

I am trying to split inputted text at spaces, and all special characters like punctuation, while keeping the delimiters. My re pattern works exactly the way I want except that it will not split multiple instances of the punctuation.
Here is my re pattern `wordsWithPunc = re.split(r'([^-\w]+)',words)`

If I have a word like "hello" with two punctuation marks after it then those punctuation marks are split but they remain as the same element. For example
`"hello,-"` will equal `"hello",",-"` but I want it to be `"hello",",","-"`

Another example. `My name is mud!!!` would be split into `"My","name","is","mud","!!!"` but I want it to be `"My","name","is","mud","!","!","!"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your pattern non-greedy (remove the `+`) if you want to capture single non-word characters, something like:

```
import re

words = 'My name is mud!!!'
splitted = re.split(r'([^-\w])', words)
# ['My', ' ', 'name', ' ', 'is', ' ', 'mud', '!', '', '!', '', '!', '']
```

This will produce also 'empty' matches between non-word characters (because you're slitting on each of them), but you can mitigate that by postprocessing the result to remove empty matches:

```
splitted = [match for match in re.split(r'([^-\w])', words) if match]
# ['My', ' ', 'name', ' ', 'is', ' ', 'mud', '!', '!', '!']
```

You can further strip spaces in the generator (i.e. `... if match.strip() ...`) if you want to get rid off the space matches as well.

Comment: You got it! Thanks a bunch

Comment: is there a way that i can use `splitted = [match for match in re.split(r'([^-\w])', words) if match]` to get rid of new lines and returns when there are two or more in a row?

Comment: @monstermatt if you want to strip spaces and newlines, as I suggested in the end, do something like: `splitted = [match for match in re.split(r'([^-\w])', words) if match.strip()]`. If you need to do more complex logic (e.g. compare two matches in a row which requires keeping a track of the last match), I'd suggest you write a separate `compare` function to do that (and any other match comparison along the way) and then just call it instead of a simple boolean match, e.g.: `splitted = [match for match in re.split(r'([^-\w])', words) if compare(match)]`.